# Continuous entropy comparison

Tags: continuous-data, entropy, signal-processing

I have a continuos time signal (speech signal) and I will add noise to it at different SNRs. I want to compare the entropy or the original signal (clean speech) with the noisy ones. The idea is to show that the entropy of the signal increases when you add noise.

¿Can I make this comparison by using the differential entropy? I know that the differential entropy lacks of the properties of the entropy in the discrete case. Even more, there are some authors that say differential entropy by itself is useless.